# error in installing Deedle.Rplugin

Tags: r, deedle

Hi I had an error when I tried to install Deedle.Rplugin

```
PM> Install-Package Deedle.Rplugin

Attempting to resolve dependency 'Deedle (≥ 0.9.12)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'FSharp.Data (≥ 1.1.10)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'RProvider (≥ 1.0.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'R.NET (≥ 1.5.5)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'RDotNet.FSharp (≥ 0.1.2.1)'.
Installing 'Deedle.RPlugin 0.9.12'.
Successfully installed 'Deedle.RPlugin 0.9.12'.
Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path     'C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\RProvider.1.0.4\lib\Deedle.RProvider.Plugin.dll'.
At C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\Deedle.RPlugin.0.9.12\tools\init.ps1:14 char:14
+     Copy-Item <<<<  $file.FullName ($destPath + $file.Name) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\RProvider.1.0.4\lib\Deedle.RProvider.Plugin.pdb'.
At C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\Deedle.RPlugin.0.9.12\tools\init.ps1:14 char:14
+     Copy-Item <<<<  $file.FullName ($destPath + $file.Name) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\RProvider.1.0.4\lib\Deedle.dll'.
At C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\Deedle.RPlugin.0.9.12\tools\init.ps1:25 char:14
+     Copy-Item <<<<  $file.FullName ($destPath + $file.Name) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\RProvider.1.0.4\lib\Deedle.pdb'.
At C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\Deedle.RPlugin.0.9.12\tools\init.ps1:25 char:14
+     Copy-Item <<<<  $file.FullName ($destPath + $file.Name) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\RProvider.1.0.4\lib\Deedle.xml'.
At C:\PF\VS\Test\packages\Deedle.RPlugin.0.9.12\tools\init.ps1:25 char:14
+     Copy-Item <<<<  $file.FullName ($destPath + $file.Name) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Adding 'Deedle.RPlugin 0.9.12' to Test.
Successfully added 'Deedle.RPlugin 0.9.12' to Test.
```

What could have been the issue?

I re-tried installing RProvider and this was the result

```
PM> Install-Package RProvider
Attempting to resolve dependency 'R.NET (≥ 1.5.5)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'RDotNet.FSharp (≥ 0.1.2.1)'.
'RProvider 1.0.5' already installed.
Test already has a reference to 'RProvider 1.0.5'.
```

Thanks

Comment: Ah, I have not noticed this question earlier! I'd recommend marking Deelde & R provided questions with the `F#` tag to get more visibility.

Comment: @TomasPetricek, thanks. will do it next time

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of R provider, we used a PowerShell script to copy various files around (so that the R provider can correctly resolve a reference to `RDotNet.dll`). This is no longer needed in the latest beta version.

If you could try installing [RProvider 1.0.7-alpha](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RProvider/1.0.7-alpha), that would be great!